# Create index in elasticsearch with different document types

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search, elastic-stack

I need to index `CLIENT` entity in elastic. My object `CLIENT` consists of few segments (JSON documents) like

```
COMMON (firstname, lastname etc),
EDUCATION (fields...),
JOB (fields...) and so on.
```

So my index has to store all these segments (JSON documents). I want to search by different combinations of fields and segments like: `search word "university" in COMMON.firstname, COMMON.lastname, EDUCATION.field1, EDUCATION.field2` and return the search results as a list of `CLIENT`s with all segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that a document can look like this

```
{
  ...common properties,
  "education": {
    ...education properties
  },
  "job": {
    ...job properties
  }
}
```

In order to index such document you can execute next query ( a new index, if does not already exist, will be created automatically )

```
PUT /client/doc/1
{
  "firstName": "...",
  "lastName": "...",
  ...other common properties,
  "education": {
    ...education properties
  },
  "job": {
    ...job properties
  }
}
```

Where **client** is the index name, **doc** is the type and **1** is the id of the new document.

And then you can get a list of clients (10 by default) by executing

```
GET /client/doc/_search
```

In order to search you can execute (this will also return max 10 docs as 10 is the default)

```
GET /client/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "firstName:university OR lastName:university OR education.field1:university OR education.field1:university",
      "default_field" : "content"
    }
  }
}
```

If you would like to explicitly specify data types for all or some of the properties please take a look at [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html). Otherwise the default data types will be assigned based on the values, like "text" for string values and etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for response. But can you clarify does this  only one solution? 
Because i have about 50-100 segments some of them change very rarely, some of them will often change many times, so i'll have to update whole document contains 100 segments even if one field from only one segment updates one time per hour, if i have 500 000 client, than i will update 500 000 whole records per hour

Comment: Elastic does not update a document, it deletes the existing one and then indexes a new one. However from user point of you Elastic supports partial updates. That means that you can submit a partial document, which will be merged with the existing one. Yes, it will be a complete rewrite of the document, but you do not need to submit the whole document.
If you worry about data consistency, then please keep in mind, that Elastic does not provide "transactions" functionality, so you may consider a traditional RDB.